# Can I have a php if statement inside a jquery script in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal-7

I have a jquery script that loads on document ready and I want to display a hidden popup if a user has already clicked a button (button field). But the condition I check is with php code.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (<?php $user_fields->field_button['und'][0]['value'] = 1 ?>) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("testpopup1").style.visibility = "visible";
    alert("x");
  }
});
</script>
```

But this way doesn't work. Is there a way to put the php code inside the if statement of my jquery code or I have to try something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Javascript to do an if and all.

In your HTML

```
<?php if ($user_fields->field_button['und'][0]['value'] === 1) { ?>

    <div id="testpopup1">Your content</div>

    <script>alert('x');</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And the onload function?The php tags should be both at the start and the end of the if statement? And I have this code at the node--XX.tpl.php file

Comment: Ok, I got it! you only missed the '=1' at the if statement, but it totally worked. I mixed js and php and I messed up, but your answer worked!

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is unnecessary here since you don't even use jQuery inside your JavaScript. Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as solved if it helped ;)

Comment: I can't upvote because I lack reputation but I mark it as solved!

Comment: Actually, the divs and the script load in both cases, even if the value is one and not

Comment: I've edited the answer, you need to use `===` for strict comparison or `==` if you want to compare with a string or other stuff. But surely NOT with `=` this is not a comparison operator

Comment: now the divs don't show up. And the value is 1, because I go to drupal users (People), and the field button of the admin is checked.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($user_fields->field_button['und'][0]['value'])`? What does it output exactly?

Comment: It was my fault. I didn't initialize the user_fileds variable in my tpl file, only at the external module file I created. Both your answer and Mike C's were correct in the first place! I was dump :(

Answer (score 1):

Save the value of the PHP value in a Javascript variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var undValue = <?= $user_fields->field_button['und'][0]['value'] ?>;
  if (undValue === 1) {
    document.getElementById('testpopup1').style.visiblity = 'visible';
    alert('x');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know much about php, but I think that the <?= part is wrong, right?Should I replace it with <?php  instead?

Comment: In fact, `<?=` is equivalent to `<?php` you can use both. But I would suggest you to be explicit and use `<?php`

Comment: @ArgirisA It's a shorthand for `<?php echo`. It definitely works.